# How to share class between two projects in dart/flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, shared-libraries

I have on project on pure dart (the server).
And another one in flutter (the client).
How can I easily share the folder lib/model with my another project?
I want to use the same collection of class in both projects.

Answer (score 3):

Create a dart package which can be used in both server and client.

```
$ dart create -t package <PACKAGE_NAME>
```

See [Creating packages](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/create-library-packages) for details.

The package can be published, used directly from git or used locally (e.g. mono repo), see [Using packages](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages).

Answer (score 1):

I can do this by

A. I create a folder `test_project`

B. In the `test_project` folder, I create the dart server project by using `dart create test_project_server` and create the folder to share anything that I want by using `dart create test_project_share`.

Now you have folders/projects `test_project_server` and `test_project_share` in the `test_project` folder.

C. Open the project `test_project_share` and create the file `share_class.dart` in the `lib` folder. Copy my example class and paste this code into this file.

```
 class ShareClass {
  static String value = "Hello World";
}
```

D. Open the `test_project_server` project and add this code below the `dependencies` of the `pubspec.yaml` file.

```
test_project_server:
  path: ../test_project_server
```

[image]

E. Run `pub get` in the `test_project_server` terminal.

Now, you can call `ShareClass` from `test_project_share` to the `test_project_server` project. Hope this will help you.